# Error in mule flow - Message payload is of type: byte[]

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I am able to get to the subflow named ***method*** (refer snippet below) using localhost url with a valid payload.
If I had to pinpoint, following xpath expression evaluation is failing

*#[xpath://Envelope/Body/add]* with an error saying *Message payload is of type: byte[]*

I have tried using transformers (byte-array-to-string, byte-array-to-object, object-to-xml etc.) but nothing seems to resolve this.

```
<flow name="version1" >
    <http:inbound-endpoint ........ />
    <set-variable variableName="req" value="#[payload:java.lang.String]"/>
    <flow-ref name="method"/>
    <catch-exception-strategy>
        <logger level="ERROR" message="Exception occurred when invoking add/update operation. The payload submitted was: #[flowVars['req']]"/>      
    </catch-exception-strategy>
</flow>

<sub-flow name="method" >   
    <choice doc:name="Choice" >
        <when expression="#[xpath://Envelope/Body/add]">
            <flow-ref name="add_v1"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[xpath://Envelope/Body/update]" >
            <flow-ref name="update_v1"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <scripting:component>
                <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
                    <![CDATA[throw new Exception("Operation not found!");]]>
                </scripting:script>
            </scripting:component>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</sub-flow>

**ERROR**

Message : Failed to invoke ScriptComponent{method.component.568157096}. Component that caused exception is: ScriptComponent{method.component.568157096}. Message payload is of type: byte[]
Code : MULE_ERROR--2
```

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
<set-variable variableName="req" value="#[payload:java.lang.String]"/>
```

you consume the inbound input stream to render it as a String.

> BTW Assuming you're on Mule 3.3 or above, you should be using MEL and not the super old expression evaluation framework, ie: `#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]` Same applies to the old `json:` evaluator (see [JSON support in MEL](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-JSONProcessing)).

So you need to set the message payload to the string you've just created in `set-variable`, replacing the now consumed input stream with its actual content:

```
<set-payload value="#[req]" />
```

Comment: I tried <set-payload value="#[payload:java.lang.String]" /> and <set-payload value = "#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" />. This does not resolve my problem. It gives me a similar error (which is same as what I got earlier using <byte-array-to-string-transformer>). The error using any of these changes to :-  Message : Failed to invoke ScriptComponent{version4_0_0.component.568157096}. Component that caused exception is: ScriptComponent{version4_0_0.component.568157096}. Message payload is of type: String
Code : MULE_ERROR--2

Answer (score 1):

In the flow version1

after the http inbound endpoint, add object-to-string transformer.
the xpath expression evalautes with out the error.