# Mule ESB 3.6 - Best way to convert BufferedInputStream to XML

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a Mule ESB project using HTTP Connector where I want to use XPath to split/route the XML.

The message payload after the HTTP Connector is a org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream.

What is the best way to transform this to a type where I can use a component such as a 'Splitter' or 'Expression' (using XPath) to split/route it?

The 'Object to XML' doesn't seem to work and the splitter doesn't work when the payload is a String (i.e. using Object to String after HTTP). I would rather not write a custom Java transformer if there are standard components that could do this?

**Flow**

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="collectionsplitterFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/CollectionSplitter" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//Order')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

**XML to split**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<msglist>
    <msg>
        <Order>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Description>Order 1</Description>
        </Order>
    </msg>
    <msg>
        <Order>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Description>Order 2</Description>
        </Order>
    </msg>
</msglist>
```

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the answer for this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142864/mule-xpath-splitter-not-working-beyond-first-element) helped provide the solution to my question.

**Answer:**

Add the NODESET option to the xpath3 MEL and then a DOM to XML transformer to convert the DOM object back to XML.

```
#[xpath3('//Order',payload,'NODESET')]
```

I also had to add all the splitting components into a sub-flow, especially for my HTTP source (as I kept getting payloadAsString() errors.

***Mule Flow***

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="PickupFile2" autoDelete="true" streaming="false" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer returnClass="java.lang.String" encoding="UTF-8" name="Object_to_XML" doc:name="Object to XML"/>
<mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer name="DOM_to_XML" doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
<flow name="collectionsplitterFlow2">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/CollectionSplitter" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="Filename" value="HTTP" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
    <flow-ref name="collectionsplitterSub_Flow" doc:name="collectionsplitterSub_Flow"/>
    <set-payload value="Response2" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
<sub-flow name="collectionsplitterSub_Flow">
    <splitter expression="#[xpath3('//Order',payload,'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Mule\CollectionSplitter\Backup\01_SplitFile" outputPattern="#[sessionVars.Filename]-split2-#[function:datestamp].xml" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" transformer-refs="DOM_to_XML" doc:name="File"/>
</sub-flow>
<flow name="collectionsplitterFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Mule\CollectionSplitter\In" moveToPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]-backup-#[function:datestamp].xml" moveToDirectory="C:\Mule\CollectionSplitter\Backup" connector-ref="PickupFile2" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="(.*).xml" caseSensitive="false"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <set-session-variable variableName="Filename" value="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
    <flow-ref name="collectionsplitterSub_Flow" doc:name="collectionsplitterSub_Flow"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your flow looks good. I tried it on my machine and I see where you're coming from. Try changing the Mule expression from #[xpath3('//Order')] to #[xpath('//Order')]. Doing so caused Mule to successfully generate two Mule messages - one for each Order element.

HTH,

Justin

Comment: Hi @Justin, thanks for the response. That change does indeed work, however the xpath MEL is deprecated in 3.6 and will be removed in 4.0 (according to the WARNING message in the console).

Comment: Agreed David, unfortunately I couldn't get it to work with xpath3.