# how to query bufferInput stream in mule esb

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am spending a lot time to understand how to convert a bufferInput stream or Dataweaveoutputhandler to other datatypes such as string or object or xml

I am constantly getting this type of error whenever I changed expression

Execution of the expression "xpath3('/*',payload,'NODESET')" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
Please help me to know if anyone has solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Exception is thrown by wrong xpath3 expression, not wrong payload type. You use xpath3 in splitter? Paste some xml, below working xpath3 expression example.

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath3('//YOUR_NODENAME',payload, 'NODESET')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
```

If you want to log payload just try:

```
<logger message="Response := #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Comment: What is //YOUR_NODENAME here? my input is BufferInputStream

Comment: You should look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544390/mule-esb-3-6-best-way-to-convert-bufferedinputstream-to-xml

Answer (score 0):

Apache provide us with great library to convert between various datatypes.
`http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/apidocs/org/apache/axis2/databinding/utils/ConverterUtil.html#convertToDataHandler(java.lang.String)`

kindly go with this.

Thanks!